# why do not display in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a react beginner learner. I do try to create the first project in react. But I can not output my project.

My react index.js is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js is:

```
import react  from 'react';
import heard_title from './component/heard_title'



export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <test />
      <heard_title />
    </div>
  );
}
```

my component is

```
import React from 'react'


export default function heard_title() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>hi</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But when the project is run why I can not show output hi?

Comment: Your components need to start with a capital letter (or PascalCase): `HeardTitle`, `Test`, etc.

Comment: see: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component

Answer (score 1):

**First of all you should share file structure of your app so that we can understand the work flow of imports in your app.**

for example

```
--- project
        -- src
              - App.js
              - index.js
              -- components
                          - heard_title.js
```

**Once check your imports "components"  or "component" directory name**

Answer (score -1):

You are violating one of React protocols!

`Warning: <heard_title /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.`

To achieve your goal, update your `App.js` like below:

```
import react  from 'react';
import HeardTitle from './component/heard_title'



export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Test />
      <HeardTitle />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It is not recommended to answer the question that has a typo...

Comment: Noted with thanks :)

Comment: Note that `<test />` still won't work.

Comment: Ya i see. Updated my answer